# Adding two int variables from a KB [Prolog]

Tags: prolog, predicate

am a Prolog newbie and am currently learning logic in computing simultaneously so please excuse my lack of coherence on this topic.

I am trying to provide a conditional that allows the user to add any two of 1, 2 and 3 to find its sum. I want to make the query take both inputs for the addition as well a third variable that holds the calculated sum:

```
?- sum(1, 2, X)
X = 3.
```

In this case I am unsure what how to define the KB in such a way that this query can be entailed. Can I avoid defining separate predicates for each number?

Thanks

Comment: If you're calculating a sum, you don't need a KB. You just need to perform the arithmetic. `X is 1 + 2`. Or more flexibly, `sum(X, Y, Result) :- Result is X + Y.`.

Comment: see plus/3, maybe it's what you want

Comment: Works flawlessly, thanks. However if I were to try and restrict the inputs to just 1,2 or 3, then wouldn't I need to implement a KB?

Comment: user needs to choose two (distinct ?) numbers from among 1,2 and 3, and their sum will be calculated, is that what you need?

Comment: A KB fact that means `1 + 2 = 3` could look like, `sum(1, 2, 3)`. Then querying `sum(1, 2, X)` would yield, `X = 3`. If you did this without defining the predicate I mentioned, then this would restrict the values to 1, 2, and 3, as shown.

Comment: @Will: Yes, those are the constraints.

lurker, Would that not restrict the input/output to 1+2=3 only?

Comment: @user3072912 yes it would restrict to `1+2=3` only. Sorry, your question regarding constraints is not very clear to me. In your simple case, you can have two facts, `sum(1, 2, 3)` and `sum(2, 1, 3)`. Those are the only valid cases in that example. Or, you can use the method Will Ness shows in his answer. It all depends upon what your overall requirements are and what kind of problem this is really an example of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
allowed_input(1).    % your
allowed_input(2).    %    knowledge
allowed_input(3).    %        base

restricted_sum(A,B,C):-
   allowed_input(A),      % test user input's
   allowed_input(B),      %    validity
   C is A+B.              % test the result
```

(according to OP's clarifications [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28257039/adding-two-int-variables-from-a-kb-prolog#comment44894539_28257039)). Testing:

> 2 ?- restricted_sum(1,2,3).  
>    true.
>
> 3 ?- restricted_sum(3,2,5). 
>   true.
>
> 4 ?- restricted_sum(3,2,15). 
>   false.
>
> 5 ?- restricted_sum(3,4,7). 
>   false.

You ask:

> Can I avoid defining separate predicates for each number?

yes, you can define instead

```
allowed_input(A):- A < 4, A > 0.
```